# Setting the Color of a TextSymbol

Tags: arcgis-10.0, c#, arcgis-engine

```
    public void DrawText( IActiveView view, string text, string fontName, int fontColor, float fontSize, IPoint point ) {

        ITextSymbol textSymbol = new TextSymbol();

        stdole.IFontDisp font = textSymbol.Font;
        font.Name = fontName;
        font.Size = (decimal)fontSize;
        textSymbol.Font = font;

        IColor color = textSymbol.Color;
        color.RGB = fontColor;
        textSymbol.Color = color;

        ITextElement textElement = new TextElementClass();
        textElement.Text = text;
        textElement.Symbol = textSymbol;
        textElement.ScaleText = true;

        IElement element = textElement as IElement;
        element.Geometry = point;

        view.GraphicsContainer.AddElement( element, 0 );

        view.PartialRefresh( esriViewDrawPhase.esriViewGraphics, element, null );
    }
```

Can anyone suggest to me why this code always sets the font and size correctly but sometimes fails to set the color correctly? I always see the correct color in the 'textSymbol.Color' property after the line that sets it to 'color.'  On the map (within a layer) it sometimes appears to 'combine' with that layer's fill color and off the map it sometimes appears 'blue.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using System.Drawing.Color.ToArgb() to convert the System.Drawing.Color that a control was returning.  I had already written:

```
public static int ConvertColorToRGB( System.Drawing.Color sourceColor ) {
    IRgbColor targetColor = new RgbColorClass();
    targetColor.Red = sourceColor.R;
    targetColor.Green = sourceColor.G;
    targetColor.Blue = sourceColor.B;
    targetColor.Transparency = sourceColor.A;
    return targetColor.RGB;
}
```

Which works.